# CodeIgniter Pagination class prevents access to other pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, pagination

tried doing this on my own but had no luck =/
My pagination is on the main page, I have some sort of blog system there,
the only other view on that controller is login, which after enabling the pagination just disappeared and now instead of URL/login it displays the main page.

My controller:

```
public function view($page = 'index') 
    {
        if ( !file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php') || $page == 'header' || $page == 'footer')
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }
        if( $page = 'index' ) {
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url'] = base_url('posts');
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->get('Updates')->num_rows();
            $config['per_page'] = 5;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pages">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['records'] = $this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->get('Updates', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2));
        } 
        $this->load->model('panel_model');
        $data['math_captcha_question'] = $this->mathcaptcha->get_question();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

routes.php:

```
$route['login'] = "pages/view/login";
```

I'd be really glad if any of you guys could give me a hand :)

Thanks!

Comment: You're implementing CodeIgniter in a weird way

Comment: Lol learned it pretty much myself, Got any suggestions? :D

Comment: The manual is pretty easy and clear, you should start there: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Comment: I'm not that bad with it, I created a whole system with it, I just make statements inside controllers >< got any ways to improve the code?

Answer (score 0):

`base_url` = assets, files and directories.

`site_url` = URL of your site, because it does append $config['index_page'].

Try replace `base_url('posts')` with `site_url('posts')`;